# GWT, mgwt and retina display

Tags: ios, gwt, cordova, retina-display, mgwt

I've implemented an iOS application based on [mgwt](http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/) and PhoneGap.

I have an image

```
<g:Image url="resources/img/topMenuTitle.png"></g:Image>
```

and two corresponding files `topMenuTitle.png` (320px by 40px) and `topMenuTitle@2x.png` (640px by 80px).

I don't know what's the best way to show the image in retina display when applied (ie, load `topMenuTitle@2x.png` when the device supports retina display and `topMenuTitle.png` otherwise).

So far I tried to use [`retina.js`](http://retinajs.com/) but it didn't work. My guess is that Retinajs processes pictures at the moment the page loads, and it does not process images that will show up later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With mgwt there is a deferred binding variable mgwt.os. It can have different values:

```
<define-property name="mgwt.os" values="iphone, ipad, retina, ipad_retina, android, android_tablet, blackberry, desktop" />
```

You can use that variable and use different resources in your app.
Take a look at the way theming is done in mgwt to see how to supply different images:

http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/Styling

if you are looking for an easy way to load an image you can do something like:

```
OsDetection d = MGWT.getOsDetection();

Image img = null;
if(d.isRetina() || isIPadRetina()){
  img = new Image("retinaurl");
}else{
  img = new Image("nonretinaurl");
}
```

Of course a better way to do this is use deferred binding, but this is okay for some images in your code.

Comment: thank you your the answer (and the great mgwt by the way), is there a way to load the image itself not its style (ie image src not background-image)?

Comment: Well, there is something missing. The image sized must be set to half when the retina image is used.

Answer (score 3):

Use DeferredBinding. Here is one example:

http://retina.teknonsys.com/

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried your suggestion but i failed due to an error (see edited question). Also is there a way to use it with UiBinder ? Thanks

Comment: In teknonsys example you do not replace bundles (which are interfaces), you replace bundle factories that produce classes.

Comment: to get my ImageResource i use `AppBundle.INSTANCE.topMenuImage()` I don't have a bundle factory. I hope i don't have to change my code logic!

Comment: well i'm not sure what's missing, but i still don't get retina images in my iPhone..

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I also tried the lib you proposed. My problem is that the retina image on the screen is also two times the size of the non-retina image on the screen. This should have the same size on the screen. Do you have any idea on this?